# Python dictionary match any element of key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If one has a dict like the following:

```
aminoacids = {
    ("GAU", "GAC"): "Asp",
    ("GAA", "GAG"): "Glu",
    ("UGU", "UGC"): "Cys",
}
```

Is there a way to match any of the elements of the key to obtain the value?

I have tried simply using `get`:

```
aminoacids.get("GAA")
```

Which returns None, as it doesn't strictly match a whole key, although `"GAA"` is contained in the key that has a value of `"Glu"`.

Is there a way to get the following behavior:

```
>>> aminoacids = {
    ("GAU", "GAC"): "Asp",
    ("GAA", "GAG"): "Glu",
    ("UGU", "UGC"): "Cys",
}

>>> aminoacids.someFunction("GAA")
>>> "Glu"
```

I've checked the docs but there doesn't seem to be a function for this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What would the expected behavior be when the same "sub-key" exists in two places? For example, GAA being in two keys?

Comment: Such a thing would never occur, as keys should be unique. What I'm trying to represent is the following table: [aminoacid table](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-SW0Fnc0Bsb8/URutxvDAaEI/AAAAAAAAAVM/0rsFvgUug1k/s1600/url.jpg). First I thought of reversing the keys to values, but search wouldnt be too efficient that way, as I must use the values to perform it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. Instead, use an alternative form to you dictionary, it's ok to have duplicate values so:

```
amino acids ={
    "GUA": "Asp",
    "GAC": "Asp",
    "GAA": "Glu",
    "GAG": "Glu",
    "UGU": "Cys",
    "UGC": "Cys"
}
```

Comment: Honestly this is the right way of doing it. If one is looking for efficiency this is the way to go. Otherwise I think the best next thing would be to switch the keys for values and get the key from a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make the setup a little more concise than the full 64-key dictionary, you could first set up a dictionary of lists (or tuples), one for each amino acid, and then build your base->amino lookup table along these lines:

```
from itertools import product
bases = 'UCAG'
amino_codes = dict(Asp=('GAU','GAC'),
                     Glu=('GAA', 'GAC'),
                     Leu=['CU'+b for b in bases] + ['UUA','UUG'],
                     Ser=['UC'+b for b in bases],  # list comprehensions just to show the concept
                     Stop=('UAA,UAG,UGA') # You do the rest
                     )

bases_to_amino = {}
for triplet in product(bases, repeat=3):
    base_key = ''.join(triplet)
    amino = next((a for (a, pat) in amino_codes.items() if base_key in pat), 'missing')
    bases_to_amino[base_key] = amino
    
from pprint import pprint
pprint(bases_to_amino)

{'AAA': 'missing',
 'AAC': 'missing',
 'AAG': 'missing',
 'AAU': 'missing',
 'ACA': 'missing',
 'ACC': 'missing',
 'ACG': 'missing',
 'ACU': 'missing',
 'AGA': 'missing',
 'AGC': 'missing',
 'AGG': 'missing',
 'AGU': 'missing',
 'AUA': 'missing',
 'AUC': 'missing',
 'AUG': 'missing',
 'AUU': 'missing',
 'CAA': 'missing',
 'CAC': 'missing',
 'CAG': 'missing',
 'CAU': 'missing',
 'CCA': 'missing',
 'CCC': 'missing',
 'CCG': 'missing',
 'CCU': 'missing',
 'CGA': 'missing',
 'CGC': 'missing',
 'CGG': 'missing',
 'CGU': 'missing',
 'CUA': 'Leu',
 'CUC': 'Leu',
 'CUG': 'Leu',
 'CUU': 'Leu',
 'GAA': 'Glu',
 'GAC': 'Asp',
 'GAG': 'missing',
 'GAU': 'Asp',
 'GCA': 'missing',
 'GCC': 'missing',
 'GCG': 'missing',
 'GCU': 'missing',
 'GGA': 'missing',
 'GGC': 'missing',
 'GGG': 'missing',
 'GGU': 'missing',
 'GUA': 'missing',
 'GUC': 'missing',
 'GUG': 'missing',
 'GUU': 'missing',
 'UAA': 'Stop',
 'UAC': 'missing',
 'UAG': 'Stop',
 'UAU': 'missing',
 'UCA': 'Ser',
 'UCC': 'Ser',
 'UCG': 'Ser',
 'UCU': 'Ser',
 'UGA': 'Stop',
 'UGC': 'missing',
 'UGG': 'missing',
 'UGU': 'missing',
 'UUA': 'Leu',
 'UUC': 'missing',
 'UUG': 'Leu',
 'UUU': 'missing'}
```

In this case you don't get all that much out of the exercise, but the concepts could be valuable for similar situations with more than 64 permutations to contend with.

Side notes:

- a purist might not like the way I mixed tuples and lists in `amino_codes`. I'll accept this as a lesser crime.
- `amino = next(blah)` is used to stop looking for a match once one is found.
- you could compress the 5 last lines of code further with nested generator comprehension. The wisdom of doing this is a matter of taste

.

```
find_amino = lambda t: next((a for (a, pat) in amino_codes.items() if t in pat), 'missing')
bases_to_amino = dict((bk, find_amino(bk)) for bk in (''.join(t) for t in product(bases, repeat=3)))
```

Comment: This is a nice way of making it shorter! Thanks :)

Comment: See the newly added side note for an even shorter version!